# Plotting ROC curve with log scale in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: roc log]

I am trying to draw a ROC plot for a binary classification problem.

```
y_true = [0, 1, 0, 1]
y_probas =  [0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 0.9]

fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_true,  y_probas)
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_true,  y_probas)
plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label="SOTW, auc="+str(auc))

plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.savefig("test.png"), dpi = 400)
```

But I am looking for ways to use the log scale in both the x and y-axis similar to fig.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `plt.xscale('log')`?

Comment: Given that the plot includes zero values, rather `plt.xscale("symlog")`